# SImulate Chrome custom tabs fall back

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

I have successfully implemented Chrome Custom Tabs for my app and it works fine across my devices.

```
CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
... customizing it here ...
CustomTabActivityHelper.openCustomTab(adapter.main, builder.build(), Uri.parse(url), new WebviewFallback());
```

I now want to simluate and test the failure in case the browser is not supported and it should fall back to my custom WebView as specified in the WebviewFallback class above.

What would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just uninstall you Chrome app on your device, or if it is installed as a system app, you just have to disable it (Settings > Applications > Chrome > Tap Disable).